# How do you attach the VS Code debugger to a running Sveltekit typescript process?

Tags: sveltekit

How do you attach the VS Code debugger in a fresh Sveltekit project?

I have created a repository [here](https://github.com/alexbjorlig/svelte-debug-breakpoints).

The **launch.json** file looks like this:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach Program",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run the project with `npm run dev` and launch the debugger, it will not break:

[image]

I tried to add sourceMap true to `preprocess` in **svelte.config.js**:

```
preprocess: preprocess({
  sourceMap: true
}),
```

Why does VS Code tell me it's an "Unbound breakpoint", when I hover the breakpoints?

This is frustrating as I have to debug some Sveltekit code, where I need the `"request": "attach"` option to work

**update**
I tried modifying the dev script to  `"dev": "NODE_OPTIONS=\"--inspect\" svelte-kit dev"`, but no help...

Comment: I'm guessing you saw this?https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1144 the latest post 3 days ago suggests to do something different than your last edit. `NODE_OPTIONS="--inspect" npm run dev`. It sounds like you might be able to work around by inserting a `debugger;` statement.

Comment: That's possible - but I want a solution without the `debugger;` statement 

Comment: Very unfortunate, hopefully the patch for that comes soon! The painful-but-quicker solution would be to build your own vitejs (and possibly svelte?) using the the changes from the referenced PR https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/3928/files